JdbcAggregateTemplate lock entities jdbc
I have this class that via JbdcAggregateTemplate, persists and do repository kind of stuff.
However, during multi thread environment I get race conditions.
I need to achive the same functionality of using @Lock in Repository.
public abstract class Listener<Item extends Event<IID>, IID>

    private final JdbcAggregateTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    protected Listener(
            JdbcAggregateTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

public <T> T upsert(UpItem<Item, T> item) {
        T oldEntity = jdbcTemplate.findById(item.id(), item.class());

        if (oldEntity != null) {
            // do stuff
            return jdbcTemplate.update(oldEntity);
        } else {
            return jdbcTemplate.insert(newEntity);
        }
    }

I'm using SpringBoot 3.2.4
How can I lock entities via JdbcAggregateTemplate in method upsert

I see that there is DataAccessStrategy.acquireLockById but it's not available in JdbcAggregateOperations's interface

